# "Уже почти" - сочетабельно ль?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Нет. Меня теперь ничто не удивляло. Скользнув равнодушным, почти
>   презрительным взглядом по буржуинским яствам, я почувствовала себя
>   героиней из романа Джеймса Чейза. Стоя в дверях и сжимая свой
>   маленький воображаемый браунинг, я холодно оглядела зал и в ответ на
>   приветливые улыбки двух симпатичных молодых людей, сухо кивнув,
>   подошла к столу. Но опустилась на стул я ***уже почти в***
>   полуобморочном состоянии. Отважиться расхаживать по залу под
>   оценивающими взглядами «творческой группы» я так и не решилась и на
>   вопрос, что предпочитаю на завтрак, почему-то сообщила: геркулесовую
>   кашу – которую вообще-то терпеть не могу.

Comment: Лучше "уже в почти..." - "почти" относится к степени обморочности (уже близко к половине обморока).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что можно так сочетать:

*Солнце стоит **уже почти в** зените и шпарит немилосердно.*
Н. Мельниченко. Еще вчера. Часть первая. Я – инженер

*Потом, превратившись **уже почти в** точку, он вдруг разом, рывком расширился и занял большую часть комнаты.*
А. Бурцев, К. Юрченко. Люди в сером

***Уже почти в*** НАТО: Украинские десантники сменили голубые береты на «береты цвета крови» (из прессы).

И ещё мне кажется, что нельзя менять "уже почти в" на "уже в почти", потому что сразу меняется смысл: полуобморочное и почти полуобморочное состояние – это разные вещи.
(Эта разница в смыслах хорошо видна в последнем предложении:
**уже почти в НАТО** или **уже в почти НАТО.**)

Answer (score 2):

1. "уже в почти полуобморочном состоянии" (Поддерживаю @Alex_ander)
2. Удивляюсь, что нет вопросов по поводу последней части — от "сообщила* и далее. По-моему, здесь уместна прямая речь, а "которую" ни к чему не клеится.

Варианты:

...почему-то сообщила: "Геркулесовую кашу", – хотя я ее, вообще-то говоря, терпеть не могу.

...почему-то сообщила, что {предпочитаю (опционально)} геркулесовую кашу (которую вообще-то терпеть не могу).

Comment: Уже поправлено на: *...почему-то сообщила: "Геркулесовую кашу!" – которую вообще-то терпеть не могу.*

Answer (score 1):

Сочетание абсолютно корректное. 
Уже - здесь частица. **Употребляется при подчеркивании или усилении значения местоимений и наречий..**

> Ср.:У. **давно** уехал кто-л. У. по глазам видно всё. У. **все** листья облетели с деревьев.

См.:Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000;

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.